# Bootstrap 4 multiselect dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select

I read on many forums that the problem of select and multiselect has been resolved after the beta version of bootstrap 4.

Unfortunately I am unable to display the multiselect as in ([bootstrap 3](https://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/had1ws54/1/)) in ([bootstrap 4](https://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/xsvw4659/1/)).

**Bootstrap 3 Snippet**

```js
$('select').selectpicker();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.8.1/css/bootstrap-select.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.8.1/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

**Bootstrap 4 Snippet**

```js
$('select').selectpicker();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Because the [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) is a Bootstrap component and therefore you need to include it in your code as you did for your V3

**NOTE:** this component only works in [bootstrap-4](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-4) since version **1.13.0**

```js
$('select').selectpicker();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Updated bootstrap-select website: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/ and github repository: https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/ in order to find the latest 1.13+ versions of the plugin which work with bootstrap 4.

Comment: @dippas selectpicker is working as expected, I need to have select "ALL" option as well. Can you help how can i do this?. Thanks in Advance

Comment: @RakeshKalwa Not sure if you still need it but you can select all options with `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('selectAll');` and deselect all options with `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('deselectAll');`.

Comment: How do you preselect it, in case of edit functionality ? Like once selected, and when i come back to edit it, i need to show last selected values.

Comment: Try this bootstrap multiselect dropdown - https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/multiselect-dropdown-list-83601849

Comment: To post all your selections, you also need to set the select name as an array:
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" name="my_selection[]">

Comment: Ho can I add values dynamically from server side to this drop down box.

Comment: would it work the same as a `dropdownlist` in asp.net mvc?

Comment: Can we add 'grouped' options to this ?

Comment: @Dnyati you after you dynamically update:  $('select').selectpicker("refresh");