# How do I make a dropdown multi select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a dropdown to be multi-select.

For example, I should be able to select Option 1, Option 2, Option 3, and Option 4 at the same time.

Just to make things more understandable. I'm attaching the desired result below:

[image]

```html
<select>
  <option>All</option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You need to search for such jQuery plugins to do that. It is not a primary feature provided by HTML. You can refer [here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/blog/Best-Multiple-Select-jQuery-Plugins.html)

Comment: HTML5 has a select multiple paramater. If you want some quick styling just use bootstrap 4. This stack post shows how to quickly style it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895806/bootstrap-4-multiselect-dropdown

Comment: Achieved with this answer. Cheers @JensIngels

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use multiple as a property of `select` tag. It is a basic feature of HTML.

Here is an example :

```html
<select multiple>
  <option value="val1">Val1</option>
  <option value="val2">Val2</option>
  <option value="val3">Val3</option>
  <option value="val4">Val4</option>
</select>
```

Or you can use any jQuery plugins for the same.

Comment: A native HTML answer rare to see but awesome. There is no reason to use jQuery or even JavaScript to simulate native HTML features

Comment: You didn't get the question. This is not a multiple-select dropdown.

Answer (score 10):

HTML has no such control.

A `<select>` element will render a dropdown menu that lets you pick one option.

A `<select multiple>` element will render a list box that lets you pick multiple options.

To get the UI you desire you will need to involve JavaScript. A good starting point would be a list of `<input type="checkbox">` elements.