# Boostrap 4 multiselect

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-multiselect

I've been struggling with bootstrap multiselect for 2 days. Only what that I could select multiple options is by holding down CTRL and then selecting although I'm trying to implement multiselect thingy that puts checkboxes or something like that in front of it...
Any help?

[image: The picture of SELECT]

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Please show us what you have right now. Without any coding or research effort, your question is a client request and therefore *off-topic* on [SO]. Please read [Ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 4 multiselect dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895806/bootstrap-4-multiselect-dropdown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want the user to see checkmarks if an option is selected. In my opinion, this is the best way to go about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50897096/11743498

It adds a **check mark** after the selected option, and it is built into **Bootstrap + jQuery**