# Show multiselectfield value in Bootstrap 4 multiselect dropdown in Django template

Tags: python, django, multi-select

I am following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895806/bootstrap-4-multiselect-dropdown) for the multi-selecting dropdown. I am using [django-multiselectfield](https://pypi.org/project/django-multiselectfield/) to collect data in the DB model. I want to show value in bootstrap multi-selecting dropdown but getting the below result
[image]

I am seeking this [result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50897096/5929910)

[image]

These are my code snippet

---

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Person(models.Model):
    obj=Country.objects.all()
    TEAM=tuple((ob,ob) for ob in obj) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=124)
    southasia=MultiSelectField(max_length=200, choices=TEAM)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404

from .forms import PersonCreationForm
from .models import Person


def person_create_view(request):
    form = PersonCreationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PersonCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('person_add')
    return render(request, 'miracle/index.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Person


class PersonCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**template**

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <title>Dependent Dropdown in Django</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Person Form</h2>

<form method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
     <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
        {{ form.southasia|as_crispy_field }}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
$('select').selectpicker();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How can do show all values in dropdown multiselect instead of normal checkbox select?

Answer (score 0):

django multiselect will give you check box view. If you want drop-down multiple list one of the work around is you can create another model for the choices and use manytomany relation . Django rendering should automatically detect it as droplist view and gives you opttion to select multiple choices.

Like this.

Class model1(model.models)
Choices = models.charfield(choice=choice)

Class person(models.model)
Choice = manytomany (model1).